Getting issue with extends class when upgraded type orm from 0.2.20 to 0.3.20
I have an entity which is extending ValidateBaseEntity.
import { Column, Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn } from "typeorm";
import { DateTransformer } from "../common/transformers";
import { ACTIVE_DIRECTORY_SETTINGS_TABLE_NAME } from "../helper/table-name";

const ValidatedBaseEntity = require("../helper/validated-base-entity").default;

export interface IActiveDirectorySettings {
  domainName: string;
  hostname: string;
  port: number;
  username: string;
  _password: string;
}

@Entity(ACTIVE_DIRECTORY_SETTINGS_TABLE_NAME)
export class ActiveDirectorySettings
  extends ValidatedBaseEntity
  implements IActiveDirectorySettings
{
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id!: number;

  @Column({ name: "domain_name", type: "varchar" })
  domainName!: string;

  @Column({ type: "varchar" })
  hostname!: string;

  @Column({ type: "int" })
  port!: number;`
}

Now i am getting this issue
/home/aquif/Desktop/version-upgrade/cleen/build/server/webpack:/cleen/src/server/db/typeorm/entity/active-directory-settings.ts:16
export class ActiveDirectorySettings
       ^
TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null
    at Object.38521 (Desktop/version-upgrade/cleen/build/server/webpack:/cleen/src/server/db/typeorm/entity/active-directory-settings.ts:16:8)
    at __webpack_require__ (Desktop/version-upgrade/cleen/build/server/webpack:/cleen/webpack/bootstrap:19:1)
    at Object.91736 (/home/aquif/Desktop/version-upgrade/cleen/build/server/webpack:/cleen/src/server/core/settings/active-directory-helper.ts:3:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (Desktop/version-upgrade/cleen/build/server/webpack:/cleen/webpack/bootstrap:19:1)
    at Object.10364 (/home/aquif/Desktop/version-upgrade/cleen/build/server/webpack:/cleen/src/server/db/typeorm/entity/user.ts:10:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (Desktop/version-upgrade/cleen/build/server/webpack:/cleen/webpack/bootstrap:19:1)
    at Object.6809 (/home/aquif/Desktop/version-upgrade/cleen/build/server/webpack:/cleen/src/server/db/typeorm/entity/user-role.ts:15:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (Desktop/version-upgrade/cleen/build/server/webpack:/cleen/webpack/bootstrap:19:1)
    at Object.90850 (Desktop/version-upgrade/cleen/build/server/webpack:/cleen/src/server/db/migrations/1627373275049-UserRolePermissionRiskAssessment.ts:3:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (Desktop/version-upgrade/cleen/build/server/webpack:/cleen/webpack/bootstrap:19:1)

I print the ValidateBaseEntity Class it is coming as null.
i am using ES2020 in tsconfig.json which is recomended for version gretaer than 0.3.0 for typeorm
